# losing my inherited class' overridden functionality: casting to base class, then pass by reference

Tags: c++, inheritance

So i have something like this...C++ MFC VS 110

```
class CObList //this is the Windows DLL class
{
   POSITION AddTail(CObject* newElement);
};

CMyClass : public CObList
{
   virtual POSITION AddTail(CObject* pObject);
};


function(CObList& list)
{
   CObject ob;
   list.AddTail(&ob);
}

main()
{
   CMyClass list;
   function(list);
}
```

when main::function() runs, and calls AddTail(), CMyClass::AddTail() is NOT ran...if it matters, CObList and function() are in a DLL.

AddTail is not virtual in CObList...can i not override it? or maybe it is because i cast my CMyClass to a CObList& and it loses the high CMyClass functions? I usually pass pointers to base classes and they find the high level functions just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to make your function virtual, as in:

```
class CBase
{
   virtual protected void AddTail(CObject* ob);
};
```

I believe that would do the trick.

Comment: see my edit. CBase is CObList in windows DLL. and it is not virtual.

Comment: however i believe you are correct. when CMyClass gets cast to a CObList, it wont recognized CMyClass functions unless they are virtual in CObList. So either i need to pass by pointer, or make CObList::AddTail virtual?

Comment: Yeah you would need to make it virtual for the overloaded functional to work correctly.